# jQuery Preloader Not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi i am using this plugin to preload all the content before displaying it. 
http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader2-preload-your-images-with-ease/

But i dont knw why this is not working.. **[HERE IS THE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/He3Ym/)**

HTML

```
<div class="preload">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500/500" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300/500" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/600/500" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400/500" />
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").queryLoader2({
        barColor: "#cccccc",
        backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
        percentage: true,
        barHeight: 3,
        completeAnimation: "fade",
        minimumTime: 200
    });  
});
```

Comment: this weird.  It doesnt work for me and i just copied the code from the website.  Perhaps its something to do with jsfiddle.  Have you tried it outside of js fiddle

Comment: Yes its working in simple page, but not working on my wordpress website, Do you know what may be causing the problem ? In my wordpress website the loader stops at 53% and then nothing happens.

Comment: @VikasGhodke well in that case the JS Fiddle isn't accurate in showing your issue. You need to link to the wordpress instance really for us to be able to help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are only testing this in JS Fiddle then the problem is that JS Fiddle adds a :

```
$(window).load(function(){
```

Which in turn is breaking your code.

If you just use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>



  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">



      <script type='text/javascript' src="http://gayadesign.com/scripts/queryLoader2/js/lib/jquery.queryloader2.js"></script>


  <style type='text/css'>

  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").queryLoader2({
        barColor: "#cccccc",
        backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
        percentage: true,
        barHeight: 3,
        completeAnimation: "fade",
        minimumTime: 200
    });  
});


</script>


</head>
<body>
  <div class="preload">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500/500" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300/500" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/600/500" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400/500" />
</div>

</body>


</html>
```

Then it works.

Comment: Yes its working in simple page, but not working on my wordpress website, Do you know what may be causing the problem ? In my wordpress website the loader stops at 53% and then nothing happens.

Comment: @VikasGhodke well in that case the JS Fiddle isn't accurate in showing your issue. You need to link to the wordpress instance really for us to be able to help :)

Comment: Yup sure i will be uploading my theme and let you know. Thanks for all your help Ryan.